# How do i move an nx library without causing this error?

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nomachine-nx

Created a fresh nx project with an angular app and a lib, tried every variation of the nx move command to try and move the lib but they all result in the same error stating it can't find the projects json, which is definitely there:

[image: nx error]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have been facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For this part, what i suggest is to simply rename the folder, project.json and tsconfig.base.json. Or create a new library from scratch and move the code into it.